# Ansible: Concatenate registered variable with string

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, ansible

I have this :

```
  # grab the internal ip [eg 10.5.20.2]
  - name: Grab the internal ip to setup the sec group rule 
    local_action: shell /sbin/ip -o -4 addr list eth0 | awk '{print $4}' | cut -d/ -f1 # returns the ip
    register: internal_ip # save the output of the above command in a var
  - debug: var=internal_ip.stdout
```

I want to set this IP in the inbound rule of an AWS security group as single host IP.

Like this: 10.5.20.2/32

How do I concatenate the `internal_ip` registered var with the string `/32` ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I scratched and bled but found it... :]

```
"{{ internal_ip.stdout }}/32"
```